# stem plot is clipped on the axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, stem-plot

I drew the plot in the image below but the axis cuts off the marker. I do not want the horizontal axis to extend beyond 0 but I want the marker to be fully visible at 0. I have seen setting `clip_on=True` to solve the problem but have not been able to do that with a stem plot. Thanks!

[image: Plot]

Here is my code below:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 6, 7)
y = np.ones(7)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 1.8))
ax.spines[["left", "bottom"]].set_position(("data", 0))
ax.spines[["top", "right"]].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('gray')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('gray')
ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)

for k, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_clip_on(True)

ax.stem(x, y, 'black', markerfmt='ko', basefmt=' ')
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.15)
ax.set_xlim(0, 6.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe change to this ? `ax.stem(x[1:], y[1:], 'black', markerfmt='ko', basefmt=' ')`

Comment: I require all these data points to be seen along with the left-most marker and the axes should not extend beyond the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right lines with `set_clip_on`, but you need to apply it to the [artist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/quick_start.html#artist) you want to show above the axes.  The `stem` method returns a [container](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/container_api.html#matplotlib.container.StemContainer) with a few artists in it, which we can loop through:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 6, 7)
y = np.ones(7)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 1.8))
ax.spines[["left", "bottom"]].set_position(("data", 0))
ax.spines[["top", "right"]].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('gray')
ax.spines['left'].set_color('gray')
ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)

stems = ax.stem(x, y, 'black', markerfmt='ko', basefmt=' ')
for artist in stems.get_children():
    artist.set_clip_on(False)
    
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.15)
ax.set_xlim(0, 6.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]